# Why can't I specify multiple types in a List in pydantic

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, pydantic, python-dataclasses

```
class Embedded(BaseModel):
    path: str
    items: list[Union[ResourceItemDir, ResourceItemFile]] # here
    limit: int
    offset: int
    sort: str
    total: int

class ResourceItemFile(BaseModel):
    name: str
    path: str
    size: int
    file: str

    resource_id: str
    created: datetime.datetime
    modified: datetime.datetime
    media_type: str
    antivirus_status: str
    comment_ids: dict
    exif: dict
    md5: str
    mime_type: str
    preview: str
    revision: int
    sha256: str
    share: dict
    type: Literal["file"]

class ResourceItemDir(BaseModel):
    name: str
    path: str

    comment_ids: dict
    created: datetime.datetime
    exif: dict
    modified: datetime.datetime
    public_key: str
    public_url: str
    resource_id: str
    revision: int
    share: dict
    type: Literal["dir"]
```

Why can't I specify multiple types in a List in pydantic?
How else can I specify that the `items` field accepts two data types?
If there are ideas how differently I should implement it?

Now such a mistake:

```
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 99 validation errors for Resource
embedded -> items -> 2 -> public_key
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> public_url
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> size
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> file
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> media_type
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> antivirus_status
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> md5
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> mime_type
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> preview
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> sha256
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
embedded -> items -> 2 -> type
  unexpected value; permitted: 'file' (type=value_error.const; given=dir; permitted=('file',))
```

Comment: A proper way to do it would be to create a `RessourceItem` class with all the attribute in common between `ResourceItemDir` and `ResourceItemFile` (keeping only the exclusive attributes in those two class). Then you will be able to use a list of `ResourceItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution using Annotated from pedantic

```
class AbstractResourceItem(BaseModel):
    name: str
    path: str
    comment_ids: dict
    created: datetime.datetime
    modified: datetime.datetime
    exif: dict
    resource_id: str
    revision: int
    share: dict
    public_key: Optional[str]
    public_url: Optional[str]


class ResourceItemFile(AbstractResourceItem):
    size: int
    file: str
    media_type: str
    antivirus_status: str
    md5: str
    mime_type: str
    preview: str
    sha256: str
    type: Literal["file"]


class ResourceItemDir(AbstractResourceItem):
    embedded: Optional["Embedded"]
    type: Literal["dir"]

#here
ResourceItem = Annotated[
    Union[ResourceItemDir, ResourceItemFile],
    Field(discriminator="type")
]


class Embedded(BaseModel):
    path: str
    items: list[ResourceItem]
    limit: int
    offset: int
    sort: str
    total: int
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Especially the usage of the "discriminator" param! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with python 3.10+ in the following way:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    friends: list[int | str] = []

u1 = User(friends=[1, 1, 'foo', 'bar', 1])
```

Comment: This does seems to work even when the items in the list are other pedantic BaseModel's, and when creating from JSON it chooses the correct BaseModel to use for each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

From Python 3.10 you can use Union types in the following way

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from pydantic import BaseModel


class F1(BaseModel):
    name: str


class F2(BaseModel):
    name: int


class User(BaseModel):
    friends: list[F1 | F2] = []


class TestPydanticFunctionality(TestCase):
    def test_allow_two_types(self):
        
        u1 = User(friends=[F2(name=1), F1(name="foo"), F2(name=1)])

        j = u1.model_dump_json()

        u2 = User.model_validate_json(j)

        self.assertTrue(isinstance(u2.friends[0], F2))
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(u2.friends[1], F1))
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(u2.friends[2], F2))
```